# Working with F# Options in C#. e.g. FSharpOption<Dictionary<Guid, MembershipUser>>

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, option-type

I'm wonder if there is a way to reduce the ugliness of dealing with option types that are returned from F# to C#. For instance:

```
 var result = TheOneCache.Get<Dictionary<Guid, MembershipUser>>(TheOneCache.EntryType.SQL, USERNAME_DICTIONARY);

 if (FSharpOption<Dictionary<Guid, MembershipUser>>.get_IsSome(result))
 {
     result.Value.Remove(membershipid);
 }
```

I'd love to not have to provide the `<Dictionary<Guid, MembershipUser>>` every time. Any way to improve this situation?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/15/making-f-type-inference-friendly-for-c.aspx

Comment: I did find that article, but I'm not sure if it applies here. I would have to explicitly create the option from scratch, while here I already have one coming from F#

Comment: I think it applies: once you have the static class from that article you can write simply `result.IsSome()` (no need to use the creation methods)

Comment: I think I see now, I'll give it a try - it works, thanks!

Comment: http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/  "Consider using the TryGetValue pattern instead of returning F# option values (option) in vanilla .NET APIs, and prefer method overloading to taking F# option values as arguments."

Comment: Thanks VB, definitely something to consider. May lead to cleaner code and more consistent with other C# libraries

Comment: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Extras/blob/master/tests/FSharpx.CSharpTests/OptionTests.cs

Answer (score 4):

@MiMo pointed me the right direction in the comments.  If anyone else comes across this problem, the following trick from [jaredpar' blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2009/12/15/making-f-type-inference-friendly-for-c.aspx) will wrap these calls up for you so you can just call `FSharpOption.isSome(x)`

```
public static class FSharpOption {
  public static FSharpOption<T> Create<T>(T value) {
    return new FSharpOption<T>(value);
  }
  public static bool IsSome<T>(this FSharpOption<T> opt) {
    return FSharpOption<T>.get_IsSome(opt);
  }
  public static bool IsNone<T>(this FSharpOption<T> opt) {
    return FSharpOption<T>.get_IsNone(opt);
  }
}
```

Comment: IsSome/IsNone leads to boolean blindness. Avoid.